# C++ 3D library to render GCode Files (Simple list of lines)

Tags: library, c++, 3d

I'm looking for a simple 3D Library to render GCode Files into a C++/Qt5.15.2 software project running on Windows.

A GCode file contains the instructions for a 3D-Printer to print a 3D Model (where to move, how much material to extrude, which layer is being printed, etc.). After parsing the GCode file, I get a list of lines representing the displacement of the nozzle and **want to display in 3D this basic list of lines**. Like in this example from https://gcode.ws/ :
[image: GCode render by gcode.ws]

This project is developed with Three.js and the 3D render is done in a 200-lines [file](https://github.com/hudbrog/gCodeViewer/blob/master/js/renderer3d.js).

**I'm looking for a similar library in C++, easy to use and sufficient, where I can just say "draw me this line". I only have lines to render, nothing else.**
To get an example I looked at the [code](https://github.com/supermerill/SuperSlicer/blob/master/src/slic3r/GUI/GCodeViewer.cpp?fbclid=IwAR3acEzk6H0Q_oGSU88-AuHu4j8lyWNayKkfpnajj6Cw_GPnJwPo14zE8Y4) of [SuperSlicer](https://github.com/supermerill/SuperSlicer) which seems to use GLEW and is way more complex. I also looked into [VTK](https://vtk.org/), which seems to offer way too much for what I want to do, and Qt3D which is a OpenGL look-alike (correct me if I'm wrong on that point please).
**Do you know any free library that would allow to do that please ?**

The files I need to display can have up to 3.000.000 lines of code.